# How to use OnLongClickListener and OnTouchListener

Tags: android

I have a code below is what i only have. I am using OnClickListener for the (16) imagebuttons for them to display string value on the (1) textbox. I am a newbie in android programming so i don't know how to do this:

1. OnLongClickListener - (if there is a listener like this)for continously tapping the buttons i need this to form a word like "Q-u-e-s-t-i-o-n".
2. OnTouchListener - i heard that i should use this one. upon spelling Q-U-E-S-T-I-O-N, right after i "untouch" the screen i want it to search the word QUESTION on my database (still studying these). Is it possible?

This code functions as : ImageButton > Displays String Value on TextView

```
OnClickListener myCommoClickListner = new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Log.i(TAG,"arg0.getId() = " + arg0.getId());

if(arg0.getId()==R.drawable.lettera){
Log.i(TAG,"arg0.getId() = " + arg0.getId());
generatedString = generatedString+ "A"; //[PLACEE RESPACTIVE CHARACTEER HERE]
text.setText(generatedString);

//For CountDownTimer                
if (!timeHasStarted) {
countDownTimer.start();
timeHasStarted = true;
}
}
else{ ....  }};
```

Please Help ..